# ASP.NET - Keeping the state of the selected value of the dropdown after refreshing the page without using viewstate and autopostback

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, webforms

I'm using an ASP.NET drop-down box and have hooked up a javascript function to "OnChange" event.

The function actually redirects the control back to the page load function in server, and refreshes the page. I'm not supposed to set the auto-post back property to true.

I'd like to make sure that the drop-down holds the selected value after the page has been refreshed.

Should I use any hidden variables or is there a property in asp.net that can help me achieve this ?

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

My code would look something like this..

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="CountriesDropDown" Width="100" runat="server" OnChange = "Send(this);"/>

function Send(dropdown)
{
//Should I write any code here ? 
refreshpage(); //separately implemented to redirect the url back to server
}

In server side

PageLoad()
{
CountriesDropDown.DataSource = CountriesList;
ContriesDropDown.DataBind();

//are there any properties that I could use so that the drop-down retains the selected value ?


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you refresh your page :

- GET : you have to add the selected value to your URL parameters
- POST : you should use a hidden field and get its value back in Request.Params[yourHiddenField.UniqueID]

Do this after your dropdownlist is bound.

Answer (score 0):

> Should I use any hidden variables or is there a property in asp.net
>   that can help me achieve this ?

Yes. Viewstate is in ASP.Net to help you achieve that. But, you don't want to use it!

What you can do now, is to append a querystring containing the selected option in your function `refreshpage` thru `onchange` handler:

```
function Send($dropdown) {
    //Should I write any code here ? 
    refreshpage(dropdown); //separately implemented to redirect the url back to server
}

function refreshpage($dropdown) {
    window.location = "MyPage.aspx?value=" + $dropdown.val();
}
```

Now in your page load of code-behind, first check if a querystring parameter called "value" is available. If yes, then set this as your selected value after databind.

```
MyAspDropDown.DataBind()
MyAspDropDown.SelectedValue = Request.Querystring("value")
```

Comment: That's exactly I've been trying to do recently. Thanks a lot. Really Helpful. will keep this updated..

Comment: Sorry, but your code doesn't work. I tried both the javascript you wrote before and the jquery method you've written now. I'm still working on it. I guess I have to use $(select#dropdownID).val()..not sure..please let me know if you find the right way. Thanks

Comment: Sure. Where exactly are you facing a problem? ASP.Net < 4? Problem with ClientId? Try `'<%= ddlAspId.ClientID %>'` or add `ClientIDMode="Static"` in your page declaration. Then you can use `$('#ddlAspId').val()`.

Comment: I've got it sorted. I used Onchange ="send(this.value)" and wrote the function as send(selected) { window.location = "" + selected;}...It works now. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score -1):

try using the update panel control.

please check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399001(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: UpdatePanel controls add a huge amount of complexity in the page (especially if there's many of them) and shouldn't be used for such trivial thing.